# Enhanced authentication issue with Azure bot framework

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I am working on an azure bot service, where I need to create a bot and use that in my website and also the mobile application. For the first time it is working fine, from next time use, it is not opening and asking for token to access the application. When I checked locally it worked and I guess, this happened when I deployed and trying to use it through azure services globally. Any help in this one is appreciated. Anyone encountered similar issue in past?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is regarding the enhanced authentication disabling in the case. Follow the steps below in Direct Line and enable the authentication in the last step. If you do not have any trusted origin, then add that trusted original.

1. Sign in to **portal.azure.com**
2. Search with **Azure bot**

[image]

Fill in the details like **Bot handle and subscription details**.
3.  Choose Channels as we need to go with creating new Direct Line
[image]

Choose **direct line** in the **Channels**

[image]

4. Create a **new site**

[image]

Get new site keys and open the open the site created. At the last you find the enable **enhanced authentication** option. Click on the toggle and make sure to check **3.0 option** also.

[image]